# Validation on checkbox where one one checkbox must be checked in laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

I have the following Checkboxes now a want put validation in checkbox that one checkbox must be checked . But i dont't know how to do that.

CheckBox

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
                                <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Arch (es) </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="inputError" style="color: red"><i
                                            id="arch_upper_error"></i></label>
                                    <div class="demo-checkbox">

                                        <input id="md_checkbox_1" name="arch_upper" value="41" class="chk-col-black"
                                               type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="md_checkbox_1">Upper</label>

                                        <input id="md_checkbox_2" name="arch_lower" value="41" class="chk-col-black"
                                               type="checkbox">
                                        <label for="md_checkbox_2">Lower</label>


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

I tried this in laravel validation but i know its wrong because it required for both but i want at least one checkbox is checked.

```
 public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'arch_lower' => 'required',
            'agarch_upper' => 'required',
         ,


        ];
    }
```

Comment: Please do not tag-spam.  Do not tag the question with jQuery and jQuery Validate if it has nothing to do with these plugins.  Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use Laravel's `required-without` method:

> The field under validation must be present and not empty only when any
>   of the other specified fields are not present.

Implementation would look something like this:

```
'arch_upper' => 'required_without: arch_lower',
```

If, by any chance, you have more checkboxes, you could use `required-without-all`:

> The field under validation must be present and not empty only when all
>   of the other specified fields are not present.

Implementation:

```
'arch_upper' => 'required_without_all: arch_lower,another_checkbox',
```

*Note: Code is not tested, if you encounter any errors, let me know.*

You can read more on Laravel's official [documentantion](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-required-without).